# How to get all measurments on Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I have a pcb design in `Eagle`. I would like to see all distances and sizes at once, such as :corner radius size, exact connectors locations and sizes, etc .

1. Is there a way to see it all at once in front of me ? if not, how you measure a distance?
2. How do I get an `STL` or other 3D file from the `Gerbers` or from Eagle ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can measure the length of a trace with the length.ulp script, though I don't know about the radius of the trace curves etc. As far as STL files, I don't know if that would be the correct file type for a 3D model output from Eagle. Since autodesk'a acquisition of cadsoft, I believe there is an 'export to autocad' like feature but I am keeping my 7.7 version so I'm not familiar with the new stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I am not interested in traces, I want to know the board physical sizes and drills locations .

Comment: My experience with mechanical design on Eagle hasn't been very good. I usually do all critical calculations/dimensions in external software/scripts and input coordinates manually or via CLI/.scr on Eagle. I'm afraid there is no shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For board sizes and other mechanical locations, there are two ways of displaying the information. One way is using the dimension tool, found on the left side right above the ratsnest tool. You pick a starting point and an end point, and you can find distances that way. Sometimes this works well, especially for the width and length of the board as you can click near the center and it will grab the entire length. For cluttered or smaller things, it doesn't work out so well.

The second way is to use the coordinates of the part you placed. This can be found by using the 'i' tool or by right clicking on the part and selecting properties. It will tell you the grid coordinate, and you can figure out distances from there; and also change the position to something more manageable usually (e.g. whole numbers).